# Error when canceling file upload in formiable-node

Tags: node.js, request-cancelling, formidable

I'm using Formiable-node for uploading files.  I'm getting the following error when attempting to cancel an upload.

```
[Error: Request aborted]

events.js:71
    throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                    ^
Error: EBADF, write
```

My code looks like the following.

```
on('field', function (name, value) {
        if(handler.req.method == "POST" && name == "customData")
        {
            var validationObject = JSON.parse(value);
                       //This is query to the db to check authorization.
            when(security.secure(validationObject.userId, validationObject.message, validationObject.hash),
                function(secureData){
                    var message = JSON.parse(validationObject.message);
                    var validTime = new Date(message.time);
                    if(validTime >= new Date())
                    {
                        options.uploadDir = __dirname + '/public/files/'+validationObject.id ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        handler.req.connection.destroy();
                    }
                },
                function(err){
                    handler.req.connection.destroy();
                });
        }
```

I'm also using https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/index.html  which is using formiable as one of the back end.

Thanks.